# Getting index of a data in an array in VUE js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change the status of Tasks when a particular method is called. But The problem is I cannot get the index of the particular item of the array to change its status.
This is my HTML:

```
<div class="main" id="my-vue-app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in completeTask">
            {{ task.description }} <button @click="markIncomplete">Mark as Incomplete</button>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in incompleteTask">
            {{ task.description }} <button @click="markComplete">Mark as Complete</button>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my Vue:

```
<script>
    new Vue(
        {
            el: '#my-vue-app',
            data:
            {
                tasks: [
                {description:'go to market', status: true},
                {description:'buy book', status: true}, 
                {description:'eat biriani', status: true}, 
                {description:'walk half kilo', status: false}, 
                {description:'eat icecream', status: false}, 
                {description:'return to home', status: false}
                ]
            },
            computed: 
            {
                incompleteTask()
                {
                    return this.tasks.filter(task => ! task.status);
                },
                completeTask()
                {
                    return this.tasks.filter(task => task.status);
                }
            },
            methods: 
            {
                markComplete()
                {
                    return this.task.status = true;

                },
                markIncomplete()
                {
                    return this.task.status = false;
                }
            }
        }
    )
</script>
```

I need make use of `markComplete()` and `markIncomplete()` but the problem is I couldn't find the way to get the index of current element to change its status.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could get the index by [declaring a second argument at the `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for):

```
<li v-for="(task, index) in incompleteTask">
    {{ task.description }} <button @click="markComplete(index)">Mark as Complete</button>
</li>
```

```js
    methods: 
    {
        markComplete(index)
        {
            return this.tasks[index].status = true;

        },
```

But a, maybe simpler, alternative is to simply **pass the `task` as argument**:

```
<li v-for="task in incompleteTask">
    {{ task.description }} <button @click="markComplete(task)">Mark as Complete</button>
</li>
```

```js
    methods: 
    {
        markComplete(task)
        {
            return task.status = true;

        },
```

Comment: For the first code I tried this method

markIncomplete()
 {
  return this.tasks[index].status = false;
 }

Error: index is not defined, how can I fix this

Comment: See, both the method usage `@click="markComplete(index)"` and the method signature should also be changed: `methods: { markComplete(index) {` .

Comment: So, fot this
<li v-for="(task, index) in incompleteTask">

is it the matter, Vue automatically take second parameter as "index"?

Answer (score 0):

### RTFM:

> You can use the **v-repeat** directive to repeat a template element
>   based on an Array of objects on the ViewModel. For every object in the
>   Array, the directive will create a child Vue instance using that
>   object as its **$data** object. These child instances inherit all data
>   on the parent, so in the repeated element you have access to
>   properties on both the repeated instance and the parent instance. In
>   addition, you get access to the **$index** property, which will be the
>   corresponding Array index of the rendered instance.

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    parentMsg: 'Hello',
    items: [
      { childMsg: 'Foo' },
      { childMsg: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@0.12.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<ul id="demo">
  <li v-repeat="items" class="item-{{$index}}">
    {{$index}} - {{parentMsg}} {{childMsg}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Source:

https://012.vuejs.org/guide/list.html

Note: *The directive **v-repeat** is available in old versions of Vue.js* :-)