# How to make Vue get data from the database each time an action happens?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button next to each row, and each row has different entries in the database. I've managed to get the information I want to appear in a Bootstrap Modal after clicking on that button. I'm still struggeling to make sure Vue updates on each click. I have the following code for the Modal:

```
<tr v-for="click in clicks">
<td><button type="button" @click="returnIndex(click)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl">{{ $t('common.moreDetails') | capitalize }}</button>
                                    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                {{ $t('entity.property1') | capitalize }}
                                                                {{ entity.somePropertyName1 }}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                {{ $t('entity.property2') | capitalize }}
                                                                {{ entity.somePropertyName2 }}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                {{ $t('entity.property3') | capitalize }}
                                                                {{ entity.somePropertyName3 }}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                {{ $t('entity.property4') | capitalize }}
                                                                {{ entity.somePropertyName4 }}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

And in my methods I have this:

```
        returnIndex(click) {
            return click.status = true;
        }
```

This method was inspired by [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697346/11480180). But I may have misunderstood it. The situation at the moment is, when I click on the the button, it shows the `somePropety` for that entity, but when you click on another entity, it still shows the same property while it should refresh (i.e. get different data).

These are some pictures to make it clear:

[image]

It shows `test` on all the 5000 entries that I have when values `test` are really only assigned to one entry. It should pick up different values for the rest, but it doesn't.

Edit: Just to be clear, the `test` should have been under `propety1/2/3/4` but didn't manage to get that to work yet, so please ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The modal is in your v-for...
Every time you click, you open all modal (and you see only the last one)

Make something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-todo-app-with-vue-gx097

PS: You can have rendering issue with the v-for without :key ...
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#key

Comment: this id has to be unique for each entity in order to make sure it renders again, right?

Comment: Because I have a unique id for that entity, but it still does the same.

Comment: by default if you don't specify the key, that use the index of the array ..
if you remove one item of the array ... the rendering algo didn't detect that all data move in the array and just rerender the last element ...

Comment: Ho i didn't see ... your modal is in you v-for O_o

Comment: After a few hours, i saw that too -_-. It created 5000 Modals each time and they were stacked above each other. Only the last one displayed on top, which is the entry with `test`. Can you maybe edit your answer to add this piece of info so that i can accept it?